# How to fix 'ng new ...' "Cannot find module" error after a fresh install?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I did on my macOS 10.12.1:

`sudo npm install -g angular-cli@latest` and then

`ng new testing-angular` on a non ~ directory and bum!

```
Cannot find module '/Users/USER/Downloads/config/environment'
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/USER/Downloads/config/environment'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Project.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/angular-cli/lib/models/project.js:280:12)
    at Project.config (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/angular-cli/lib/models/project.js:198:26)
    at Class.Blueprint.install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/angular-cli/lib/models/blueprint.js:498:32)
    at Class.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/angular-cli/lib/tasks/install-blueprint.js:53:24)
    at Class.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/commands/init.js:105:33)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:538:12)
    at invokeCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:553:13)
    at publish (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:521:7)
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2373:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

When I executes the same `ng new testing-angular` inside my home dir ~ i don't get any error.

Any idea why I'm getting this error and how to avoid it?

Comment: can you explain problem more?.

Comment: @RumesShyaman I was trying to create a new project after a fresh installation and got that error. Pls, let me know what else do you want to know. Thanks.

Comment: are using angular cli   ?

Comment: what you mean by non ~ directory

Comment: @RumesShyaman I'm using cli. ~ directory = home directory. In my case `/Users/USER`